# One graph a subgraph of another?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices with minimum degree $\delta$ and with its largest independent set $a>\delta$. Consider the graph $\bar{K}_a \otimes K_{n-a-1}$ (in other words, take a set of $a$ points and add every edge relation between that set and $K_{n-a-1}$. Intuitively, this graph is a $K_{n-1}$ with a missing $K_a$).

How does one prove that that no matter how I take a vertex $v$ and connect it to $\delta$ vertices in the $\bar{K}_a$, I will always get a copy of $G$.

I think this is trivially true for bipartite graphs, but I dont know how to prove it in general. Any help is nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true. Consider a star.